# How to edit the styles for the table of pages/post listed in the admin when you click on pages/posts?

Tags: php, post-class

It seems that some of the css on the table that shows the list of all the pages adversely reacts with one of my plugins, which adds a bunch of columns to the table. I'm pretty sure this is edit.php. At least, that's what's in the URL.

Using the developer tools in Chrome I noticed that the table contains a class called `fixed`, which adds `table-layout:fixed` to the table styles. Removing it clears up the problem.

The question is, how do I edit the styles for this table?

Here's the relevant code:

```
<form id="posts-filter" method="get">
...
<h2 class='screen-reader-text'>Pages list</h2>
<table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped pages">
```

The form element is the closet parent with an ID. The table with class `wp-list-table` is what needs to be targeted. Removing the `fixed` class fixes the problem, at least in the developer tools. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of a hack fix, I installed Tampermonkey for Chrome (a userscript manager) and created the following userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Fix edit.php!
// @author       You
// @match        http://www.example.com/wp-admin/edit.php*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...

    function addGlobalStyle(css) {
        var head, style;
        head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        if (!head) { return; }
        style = document.createElement('style');
        style.type = 'text/css';
        style.innerHTML = css;
        head.appendChild(style);
    }
    addGlobalStyle('.fixed { table-layout:auto !important; }');

})();
```

It's light, so it doesn't slow down the page at all. As far as I can tell, the problem doesn't exist anymore since a WP update, but I still have the userscript just in case.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are in edit.php so you can add style only for this admin page.

```
function enqueue_my_scripts($hook) {
if ( 'edit.php' != $hook ) {
    return;
    }
  //our script to remove fixed table class
 echo '<script>';
 echo '$( ".wp-list-table" ).removeClass( "fixed" )';
 echo '</script>';

}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts' );
```

The explanation is basic first we check if we are in edit page then execute the remove class.

Comment: And drop this into `functions.php`?

Comment: Though I'm sure this would work, isn't there a way to just prevent the class from ending up on the styles for this table in the first place? Where are all these classes added to this table?

Comment: Yes. Drop it in functions.php

Comment: @fredsbend CSS classes are added in `WP_Posts_List_Table ()` class. If you implement your own post list you can override the `get_table_classes()` function.